Where does TOGAF define artifact (diagram) content
Where does TOGAF define artifact / architecture view / diagram content?
In Part IV Architecture Content Framework  - 31.6 there seems to be a list of 30+ diagrams. There's also a very short outline description of each. I can't, however, find a definition of each artifact / diagram.
I'd expect each diagram definition to identify elements from the TOGAF Content Metamodel. I've found a template download but this doesn't define anything and can't be related to the TOGAF metamodel.
